# Como usar el LIKE como parametro en una funcion en postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql

Hola a todos es que estoy intentado pasar una consulta que uso regularmente a una función pero me encuentro con problemas para crearla. Lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."prueba" (in regional varchar, in fecha date) RETURNS TABLE(num_recepcion varchar, nombre varchar, nit varchar, nombre_ips varchar, total int4, tipificacada int4, devuelta int4, fecha_recepcion date, fecha_asignacion date, nombre_operador varchar, tipo int4) AS
'
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY

SELECT
    TIPI."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
    TIPI."NIT_IPS",
    TIPI."NOMBRE_IPS",
    TIPI.Total,
    TIPI.Tipificadas,
    DEVUELTA.devultas,
    TIPI."FECHA_RECEPCION" AS Fecha_Entrada,
    CF."FechaAsignacion" AS Fecha_Asignado,
    TIPI."NOMBRE_OPERADOR_ASIGNADO",
    TIPI."ESTADO" 
FROM
    (   SELECT
            Y."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
            RF."NIT_IPS",
            RF."NOMBRE_IPS",
            Y.Total,
            Y.Tipificadas,
            RF."FECHA_RECEPCION",
            RF."NOMBRE_OPERADOR_ASIGNADO",
            RF."ESTADO" 
        FROM
            "t_RecepcionFacturacion" AS RF,
            (   SELECT
                    X."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
                    SUM(X.total)       AS Total,
                    SUM(X.TIPIFICADAS) AS Tipificadas 
                FROM
                    (   SELECT
                            SUB."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
                            COUNT(*) total ,
                            COUNT (SUB."ESTADO") AS TIPIFICADAS 
                        FROM
                            (   SELECT
                                    DISTINCT DRF."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
                                    DRF."NUMERO_FACTURA",
                                    DRF."ESTADO",
                                    DRF."ESTADO_RECEPCION"                                   
                                FROM
                                    "t_DetalleRecepcionFacturacion" AS DRF 
                                    JOIN "t_RecepcionFacturacion" AS RF 
                                    ON DRF."NUMERO_RECEPCION"= RF."NUMERO_RECEPCION"                                    
                                WHERE
                                    RF."FECHA_RECEPCION" = fecha AND
                                    RF."NUMERO_RECEPCION" LIKE regional||'%') AS 
                            SUB 
                        GROUP BY
                            SUB."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
                            SUB."ESTADO") AS X 
                GROUP BY
                    X."NUMERO_RECEPCION") Y 
        WHERE
            RF."NUMERO_RECEPCION" = Y."NUMERO_RECEPCION") AS TIPI 
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                        rf."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
                        RF."NIT_IPS",
                        RF."NOMBRE_IPS",
                        X.devultas 
                    FROM
                        "t_RecepcionFacturacion" AS rf,
                        (   SELECT
                                SUB."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
                                COUNT(*) AS devultas 
                            FROM
                                (   SELECT
                                        DISTINCT DRF."NUMERO_RECEPCION",
                                        DRF."NUMERO_FACTURA" 
                                    FROM
                                        "t_DetalleRecepcionFacturacion" AS drf 
                                    WHERE
                                        drf."NUMERO_RECEPCION" LIKE regional||'%' 
                                    AND
                                        drf."ESTADO_RECEPCION"='8') AS SUB 
                            GROUP BY
                                SUB."NUMERO_RECEPCION")                        
                        AS X 
                    WHERE
                        rf."NUMERO_RECEPCION" = X."NUMERO_RECEPCION") AS 
        DEVUELTA 
        ON TIPI."NUMERO_RECEPCION"= DEVUELTA."NUMERO_RECEPCION"
        JOIN "t_ConsecutivosRecibidos" AS CF ON TIPI."NUMERO_RECEPCION" = CF."NumeroConsecutivo";
END
'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Pero me genera error al intentar crear la función, me dice que tengo un error en regional||'%'
Les agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La comilla simple **(')** que abres en el Like esta cerrando la que abriste al iniciar la declaracion de tu funcion, por lo que el simbolo de porcentaje no se está tomando como una cadena, de hecho si te fijas incluso el color esta cambiado

intenta poniendo

```
LIKE regional||''%''
```

es decir dos veces cada comilla simple